Apache AD authentication with same username in multiple domains
We're having (because reasons) multiple AD domains, all having their own pair of domain controllers. Users can have accounts in any single domain or combination of domains. In the latter, the username is the same in all domains, but with different passwords.
We also have a web-based application running on Apache that requires users to authenticate. It is possible to have a AuthnProviderAlias for each domain, and use these aliases in AuthBasicProvider to allow authentication on all domains. So far, so good.
It turns out that the order of the aliases in the AuthBasicProvider directive is important because an "authentication failed" will cause Apache to stop trying to authenticate the user in any other domain. Is there a directive to treat "authentication failed" in the same way as "unknown user" to have Apache try to authenticate the user in the next domain?

I'm not very into that topic, but one workaround could be to just run multiple Apache HTTP servers on the same machine, but using different IP for each HTTP server. Then you could do some tricky package redirects using iptables (detecting the AD domain and redirecting to the right HTTP server IP).

PS I've no idea how performance friendly such solution would be, maybe there is a better option
